# What happened to Vidar?

Tags: support, tags, users-page

Roaming around as ever, I stumbled upon Vidar's avatar and noticed his "credentials" were missing:

[image: Vidar's credentials]

Why are the tag descriptions missing? Lost in the matrix? Eaten by bugs?

Edit: 19-11-2013 14:53: it's not a bug, but a virus !!

[image: Further example]

OS: Chrome OS, Browser: Chrome OS. I've noticed the same on my Nexus 4.

Comment: Same on Safari.

Comment: But only on the week’s reputation page; on every other one the tags are present.

Comment: Thanks for caring :) I see the same on my Chrome browser on Windows XP. It seems it's not just rendering problem, the HTML looks like `<div class="user-tags">
                                    
                                </div>`

Comment: I can't seem to repro it now on Chrome stable on Win 7. Perhaps it's fixed

Comment: @Sathya Same situation as before (also stable Chrome)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only tags associated with questions or answers that were up- or down-voted in the current week (or month, or whatever time-period selected) are displayed on that page. The current week begins on 2013-11-17 at 00:00:00 UTC.

Vidar hasn't gained or lost any reputation from up- or down-votes during the current week. His reputation so far has come from an accepted answer and a bounty. Therefore, he has no eligible tags to display.

Comment: I'm glad it wasn't a virus or bug for that matter !!